# Nav looks different on different pages, why?

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav, navbar

I can't for the life of me figure out my the Nav bar has some extra padding or margin on top only on pages other than the Homepage. on the homepage it looks right.

I've spent hours on this and am at my wits end.

You can see the site [here](http://premierperspectives.net/)

Click on about us or on the blog post and see it change.
This template is a bit messy in terms of css (at least to me), and I couldn't figure out what actually changes on other pages.

I hope someone can help here.

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: page_item page-item-2  these classes are not on the home page. It may be worth while to look what the css is doing with these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `#header` div of your page there are two `h1` and `h2` tags on your homepage, the `h1` heading is including just text inside of it, then when you switch to your "About Us" page those tags turn into `h2` and `h3` and the `h2` heading is filled this time with an anchor and that is whats pushing your menu down, the padding on these tags. So switch that heading to an `h1` on your "About Us" page for a Heading 1 page title tag and it works fine, otherwise you will have to modify your css to adjust the padding/margin on these tags.

Comment: This really helped me understand where the issue came from. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you define `h3 margin : 0;` in your css file than your page is fine.

as like this

```
#header > h3{margin:0;}
```